# Calculating GMSPolygon area

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Cannot find any straightforward solution to calculate GMSPolygon object area. Is there some way to do that or I have to calculate it with sides lengths and some mathematical computations?

Comment: `GMSGeometryArea` ?

Comment: @Larme big thanks! I don't know why couldn't I find it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Larme; `GMSGeometryArea` is the solution.